# Does 'force_style' work with 'subtitles=video.mkv' for FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, python, video-encoding, subtitles, ffmpeg-filters

I am using this script to encode an burn in subtiles for an entire folder:

```
for filepath in newFiles:
    video = os.path.basename(filepath)
    videoName = os.path.splitext(video)[0]
    newFile = '%s.mp4' % videoName
    i = filepath
    o = os.path.join(destinationDirectory, newFile)
    if os.path.isfile(o):
        continue
    encodeCommand = f'ffmpeg -i "{i}" -vf "scale=-2:480, subtitles="{video}":force_style='PrimaryColour=&H0300FFFF&'" -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -preset fast -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p "{o}"'
    print('Encoding %s' % newFile)
    encode = os.popen(encodeCommand).read()
```

However, the `force_style='PrimaryColour=&H0300FFFF&'` does not work and just keeps the subtitles built into the original file untouched. I am using `subtitles="{video}"` because it uses the subtitles that are saved in the video file. Does `'force_style'` only work if I am providing a separate subtitle file?

I tried a mixture of quote combinations to see if that was the problem, but that stopped the script from running. This script still runs, just doesn't change the color of the subtitles.

Edit: suddenly it doesn't run. Says that PrimaryColour is invalid syntax. I didn't change anything

Comment: What is the format of the subtitles stream in `video.mkv`? Check the format using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), or FFprobe.

Comment: .ass. Since this post I actually got it to work with one attribute by doing `force_style="PrimaryColour"=&H0300FFFF&`. But once I try to add more than one attribute, I can't get any syntax to work.

Comment: Try putting all the style options `force_style='...'` as described [here](https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-add-subtitles-to-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg/#optional-styling-the-subtitles). Example: `"subtitles=video.mkv:force_style='Fontname=Roboto,OutlineColour=&H40000000,BorderStyle=3'"`. In case it's working from command line, and the issue is related to the Python syntax, please ask the question in StackOverflow site.

Comment: I asked in StackOverflow and they closed my question because it was about ffmpeg.
Anyway I got it to work. Ended up being an issue with the f-string. I changed it to open an close with triple quotes, so I could use the single quotes that ffmpeg requires for styling.
`encodeCommand = f'''ffmpeg -i "{i}" -vf "scale=-2:480,subtitles={video}:force_style='PrimaryColour=&H0300FFFF&,MarginV=50'" -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -preset fast -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p "{o}"'''`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the f-string. It was opened and closed with single quotes, so any single quotes inside caused syntax issues. Open and close with triple quotes, so the single quotes can be used for styling.

```
encodeCommand = f'''ffmpeg -i "{i}" -vf "scale=-2:480,subtitles={video}:force_style='PrimaryColour=&H0300FFFF&,MarginV=50'" -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -preset fast -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p "{o}"'''
```